# Almost virus infected like battery draining in our laptop. Under healthy conditions

Tags: battery, virus

Someone please reach out to us.

A week ago we accidentally got so called ' sonbokli' virus. Thankfully it was detected by windows security and blocked. A day after our laptop battery started draining minute by minute. And we tried reinstalling **windows**,**bios/Uefi firmware** but nothing. And then we thought it was something with our laptop battery because we did everything to save power and **optimize the battery**.
We then thought our WiFi is infected too so we **resetted the router** several times. But it was until today we resetted our Mobile phone which was *once connected to our WiFi as well as our laptop for mobile tethering.*
So today, we thought of reinstalling windows again to clear out our problem once and for all. So we secretly took our dad's laptop to make a **clean windows bootable drive**.This is how we previously reinstalled windows several times. when connected it to our WiFi, dad's laptop started draining battery like crazy. From **20% to 7% in a matter of 4 minutes**. This was really unlikely (because we used it before). But now we are desperate and staying up all night to do something because the laptop is really important for our Dad. Initially we didn't really thought our wifi is hacked too. But earlier today  we have to call their hotline because it was not connecting. Also we couldn't configure it with PPPoE usernames or Password in our router's firmware. So as they said our configuration were changed somehow so we got our configurations back. But we really didn't care at that time.
**The reason we talked all these stuff is to make sure you might find link of any of these scenarios to fix this problem.**
Please be kind enough to tell us something to do.

**But the most weird part is no antimalware software detected it nor it was heated up so bad**. Windows task manager didn't show anything suspicious at all. *But still the battery is draining most unnaturally*.

We really want to fix our mistakes or our Dad will be in huge trouble. We really need your help.

Our laptop : acer aspire 5 a515 54g

Dad's laptop: Asus expertbook b1500c

Comment: Secure your router.  Make sure you disabled remote access. Change the password of your wireless to a strong password.  Reinstall your dad's computer and hacking will no longer be a reason for the battery to drain.

Comment: "Reinstall your dad's computer" sounds like a bad idea to me @John.  What if it were your kids and your computer?  What if they wipe out his work?

Comment: I suggested the reinstall to ensure no viruses after securing the network to remove the causes mentioned in the original post. That was why. You have to back up first of course.

Comment: Do you guys think after resetting this wifi with a strong password will make sure it will get quarantined in the laptop only.

Comment: Just change the password on the access point although I would argue that it's unnecessary. Resetting the access point isn't necessary.  The malware that was downloaded targeted your OS not your access point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malwarebytes_(software)

Answer (score 0):

It is at least possible that in addition to 'sonbokli', your computer has had other software added that is not in your best interests.  At a guess, based on the power drain, would be a crypto-currency-miner.

Second, one of the 'features' claimed for this malware (by pcrisk.com, so no idea how reliable that is) is credential stealing, so if you have another device you haven't used in this recovery effort, you (and other users of the computers) should consider using it to change all of the passwords associated with people who use either computer.

Further, if you are swapping media back and forth with a previously un-affected computer, and that computer starts coming down with symptoms (the second laptop), I would be very cautious how you move forward, to avoid infecting additional systems.  One strategy is to consider any device that has any storage (e.g. thumb drive, portable disk drive) that you plug into one of the two affected computers to be permanently tainted, never to be used in a clean computer again.

Finally, you should probably tell the owner of the second laptop.  Yes, it is embarrassing and you could get in trouble, but the alternatives are:

1. You tell them now, and they can limit the impact to their work, OR
2. They find out later, after the impact to their work is greater, and they see you being less than completely honest, causing them even more problems / trouble.

If they were expected to prevent you from using the laptop, they are in the same position you are, so better to work with them.

Comment: Thank you very much to your advice. We will stick with the first alternative. We will also try to get help from local tech shop for more security. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I'm sorry this happened to you, I wish you the best of luck.